# Best way to implement a WebSocket project, using python on Windows

Tags: django, windows, websocket, django-channels

I use Django Channels for WebSocket, but I can't find a way to deploy it on Windows. I can't change my platform so switching to Linux is not an option.
Could you please suggest a way to deploy Django Channels on Linux?
Or Do you know what is the Django Channels alternative for Windows?

Comment: I think you need to mention what exact problems do you having with using Django Channels on Windows.

Comment: one thing you will hit is the limited number of open connections that python can handle on windows this seems to default to 500 connections per process.

Comment: @Charnel Thank you. I couldn't find any straightforward guide for setting up Django channels on Windows. I'm using IIS for serving WSGI, but It seems there is no way to deploy ASGI using IIS.

Comment: @user3509264 if you were to run channels in production on windows you would not use ISS it would need to handle all the traffic directly.

Answer (score 0):

Django channels also implement with  redis server. redis server  available on window.

use Django Channel Layer with redis server.
channel layer use web-socket between Django application and socket layer.
please follow this link [Channel-Layers](https://pypi.org/project/channels-redis/)

Comment: redis on windows is not yet considered production stable.

Comment: I'm using RabbitMQ as my channel layer backend.

Comment: Actually there is a stable, production-grade, Windows port of Redis.  It's called Memurai. 
It has a free developer edition in addition to the commercial license.